# Unable to edit link behavior for iOS app from console

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using dynamic links in my Android and iOS Firebase apps and although I have no problem saving the link, when I try to define the link behavior for iOS by choosing "Open the deep link in your iOS app" followed by pressing **Next** and **Edit Link**, the selection doesn't get saved:

[image]

[image]

Has anyone experienced this problem? Everything else gets updated in the dynamic link except the link behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out that this was happening because the App Store ID hadn't been set in Firebase Project settings. Once I added it (the Team ID had already been set), I was able to save the edit.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve the same result with the same problem on Android? @FractalBob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029462/firebase-unable-to-edit-dynamic-link-behavior-for-android-app-from-console

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy over this. Can't believe that the console won't give any feedback to warn the user about this.